# Fill in ID Spaces Phpmyadmin / PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Hey well right now I have a mysql table thats called id set to int 11 primary auto increment. Essentially all it's doing is storing the id for data entries, but occasionally i'm deleting some of them leaving spaces in between the id's

ex :

the id might go from 229 to 298 because i deleted all the ones in between.

I'm just wondering if it's possible to make it so any new entries automatically are assigned an id that is in between those two numbers. (An id to fill in the blank space)

Thanks

Comment: This is a false problem. You don't have to care about missing IDs. Any try to modify natural behaviour of autoincrement field is misleading.

Comment: the thing is, for my script i'm having a button where they click it and it goes to the next entry, the only way i really know how to do this is just add one to the current id, but in the case the next one may not be there. Any idea around that?

Comment: This is more of a coding issue, but a way to go around it would be when you are quering for the currentId + 1 simple make it something like this `select * from tableX where id >= currentId +1 LIMIT 1` which will get you the first id after the currentId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the thing is, for my script i'm having
>   a button where they click it and it
>   goes to the next entry, the only way i
>   really know how to do this is just add
>   one to the current id, but in the case
>   the next one may not be there. Any
>   idea around that?

Remember the current id and the select the next row. So, when viewing a row with an `id` of 50 you can select the next row. For instance:

```
+-----------------+
+ id | title      +
+-----------------+
+ 50 | a record   +
+ 57 | another    +
+ 98 | and more   +
+ 99 | last one   +
+-----------------+
```

The following query:

`SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE id > 50 LIMIT 1`

Will return the record with an `id` of `57`.

While this query:

`SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE id > 98 LIMIT 1`

Will return the record with an `id` of `99`.

You can pass in the current record via `$_GET` and PHP can build the SQL statement accordingly.